# JBoss use host name instead of localhost then lost css and javascript effects

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jboss7.x

After changing the `standalone.xml` from `127.0.0.1` to `any address`

```
    <interface name="public">
       <any-address/>
       <!-- <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>-->
    </interface>
```

After using host name or ip instead of localhost or 127.0.0.1,
all of sudden the jsp application lost part of css and dojo decoration on the page. What could be the cause of the issue?

We are on JBoss EAP6.

Answer (score 0):

A network interface is declared by specifying a logical name and a selection criteria for the physical interface. The application server ships with a default configuration for a management and a public interface name. In this configuration, the public interface group is intended for use by any application-related network communication such as Web or Messaging.

[Red Hat Jboss EAP Admin Guide](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.1/html-single/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/index.html#sect-Interfaces)